# Removing entire excel row by searching for specific words using C#

Tags: c#, excel, rows, erase

I am new to C# and have been trying to make my very own little tool to help me at work.
For the most part I've got everything i needed done but I need to do one more thing to have the entire program work as i want it too.

I need to go through my excel file, search for a specific word, (or other criteria) and when that specific word is found, the entire row on which it was found to be deleted.

So far i haven't had much luck in finding the proper code to help me succed in this.

Any help or suggestions would be of most help and would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Here is a part of my code:

**This part is used to activate my macro:**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excel.Visible = true;
            //3
            Workbook wb1 = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\amohan\AppData\Local\Temp\amohan.xls");
            Workbook wb2 = excel.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\amohan\Desktop\Saw pt. Test\Saw.xlsm");
            //4
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range source = wb1.Sheets["amohan"].Range("A1:X10000");
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range destination = wb2.Sheets["bom"].Range("A1:X10000");
            //5
            source.Copy(destination);
            wb2.Activate();
            excel.Run("Macro2");
            //6
            wb1.Close();
            wb2.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\amohan\Desktop\Saw pt. Test\I.O. (date&time)\Formatare - "
            + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy - ") + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh.mm.ss") + ".xlsm");
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
            wb2.SaveAs(@"C:\Users\amohan\Desktop\Saw pt. Test\Replaceable Excel File.xlsm");
            wb2.Close();
            excel.Quit();
            GC.Collect();
```

**and this part is for copying it to further paste the info (final step)**

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application sourceApp;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook sourceWorkBook;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet sourceWorkSheet;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range sourceRange;
            string sourcePath;

sourcePath = (@"C:\Users\amohan\Desktop\Saw pt. Test\Replaceable Excel File.xlsm");
            sourceApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            sourceWorkBook = sourceApp.Workbooks.Open(sourcePath);
            sourceWorkSheet = sourceWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(3);
            sourceRange = sourceWorkSheet.UsedRange;
            sourceRange.Copy(Type.Missing);
            excel.Quit();
            GC.Collect();
```

I just need to eliminate some info before copying it to my clipboard.

Comment: Please share the code to get more insight

Comment: I have added more details about what I'm trying to do/achieve.